# ADG drawVerticalLine issue

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

I have an issue on the AdvancedDataGrid that the verticalLines are not always drawn correctly when the Grid is scrolled

Screenshot:
[image]

As you can see it afflicts the entire row up to first groupedColumn.
This happens only when it's upscrolling.
First I thought that it's probably an issue with my itemRenderer
but that is not the case because I found that it's only happing when I set the lockedColumnCount property.
In my case it is set to 10, just to scroll only the groupedColumns.
Without lockedColumnCount there is no such an issue with the lines.

It has nothing to do neither with the footer row, I had the same issue already before I added it.

Anyone has the same problem and found a workaround?

Comment: a workaround is to add a ScrollEvent.SCROLL event listener to the ADG and call the adg invalideDisplayList function inside the handler. It works but that is not a very great solution because it slows the adg down even more then it already is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful investigations I found the reason or at least the origin of this behaviour.

It happens only when:
*using grouped columns
*set lockedColumnCount for the ADG
*using a subclass of MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer for your itemRenderers

this will produce the bug you can see above when the adg is scrolled up 

(it newer happens when it's scrolled down)
it disappears when the grid is redrawn

 (after sort or column drag etc.)
and comes back most time (but not every time) when it is rescrolled...

**Conclusion**:
Don't use the MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer when you have groupedColumns and a lockedColumnCount

Create a class which implements:
IDataRenderer, IDropInListItemRenderer, ILayoutManagerClient, IListItemRenderer, IStyleClient

(subclass something like "Group" so you don't have to implement everything,

get inspired from the default renderer AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer for the rest of the implementation)

and use that class for your renderer

and no scrolling drawVerticalLine bug should appear...